# When is $AA^T$ a strictly positive definite matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, positive-definite

Suppose that $A$ is a $m$ by $n$ matrix, where $m>n$. When I use numerical calculation, sometimes $AA^T$ is strictly positive definite, the other times $AA^T$ is singular. Are there any sufficient conditions for $A$ to satisfy so that $AA^T$ is a strictly positive definite matrix?

Comment: If $m>n$ it is always singular because it is $m\times m$, but its rank cannot be more than $n$. $A^TA$ can be strictly positive definite if rank$\,A=n$.

Comment: It helps to know that $A^T$ and $A A^T$ have the same null space. Proof: $A^T x = 0 \implies A A^T x = 0 \implies x^T A A^T x = 0 \implies \| A^T x \| = 0 \implies A^T x = 0$.

Comment: Assuming you meant $m<n$ the answer is: $AA^T$ is positive definite if and only if $A$ has full rank (namely $m$). I don't know what *strictly* positive definite means though.